# i can't find the problem to this formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, google-sheets-arrays

=UNIQUE(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1xWx1FRfvCfmvYi9Sb7Gh5lIAb-NAt0RG0h-e_HKmxjU","APP Directory!A2:U");IMPORTRANGE("1xWx1FRfvCfmvYi9Sb7Gh5lIAb-NAt0RG0h-e_HKmxjU","APP Directory!A2:U")},"Select * Where Col1 is not null order by Col4 Asc",1))

This is what I get as an error:

Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col4

Comment: Without being able to see the spreadsheet and test things, there is little we can tell you. I also don't understand why you'd have the same range stacked on top of itself, as shown in the formula post.

Comment: Hi. Would you please edit your question to clarify: 1) Do you have access to this external spreadsheet? 2) what is the data layout in `APP Directory!A2:U` 3) As mentioned by @ErikTyler, why are you stacking the same data from the same sheet? 4) The error appears to be related to the second of the `IMPORTRANGE` data sets. If that parameter is removed from the formula, there is no error. Have you tried removing the second query range? 5) The data range (A2:U) covers 21 Columns, but your `select` and `where` condition cover only 4 Columns. Why didn't you declare a range of "A2:D"?

Comment: hI, I am copying my old system and now is giving that error a friend of mine built it for me and I can't get in touch with anymore.

Comment: Erik Tyler, someone built me a CRM of Google sheets it is working great for my small business but every year I create a new copy to start fresh again. but I am getting this error. even though it is the same formula that it is working now but when i made a copy gives me that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try [authorizing](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/24943424?msgid=25532932) the `importrange()`. In the spreadsheet where you have the issue, put this in a free cell:

`=importrange("1xWx1FRfvCfmvYi9Sb7Gh5lIAb-NAt0RG0h-e_HKmxjU", "A1")`

Chances are that the new formula cell will display a red corner flag. Click it to authorize the import. After that, your existing formulas that use `importrange()` should start working as well. You can delete the new formula cell after that.